# How to verify firebase issued jwt using python

Tags: python, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-authentication, jwt

I have an AWS lambda function, which I need to deploy as EC2 server.
This lambda has a authorizer, which I'm having trouble "copying" it's mechanism.
The lambda is receiving HTTP requests with a jwt. It doesn't receive the public key, only the issuer URL and audience, and manages to verify the token being sent.
I need to do this verification myself now, but I just can't. There is something I'm missing.
The project has to use jwt assigned by a Firebase project, which I don't manage, but can ask the owner for help if needed.
My project id is `orca-ai-dashboard`, and the issuer url is `https://securetoken.google.com/orca-ai-dashboard`.
I've read that I need to get the public key, by sending get request to  `https://securetoken.google.com/orca-ai-dashboard/.well-known/jwks.json`, but this URL return 404 and no public key.
What is the mechanism behind the authorizer?

Answer (score 0):

While making a request to the domain of the URL in the `iss` claim followed by `/.well-known/xxx` is a widely used standard, it is not used in all JSON Web Token implementations.
Unfortunately there are a number of competing URLs used for obtaining a JWKS file, including:

- `/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`
- `/.well-known/jwks.json`
- `/.well-known/oauth/openid/jwks/`

In almost all cases, you can request `/.well-known/openid-configuration` and then follow the returned `jwks_uri` URI.

---

However, for Firebase ID tokens, you need to use the endpoint mentioned in the documentation on [verifying ID tokens using third-party JWT libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library):

> Ensure that the ID token was signed by the private key corresponding to the token's `kid` claim. Grab the public key from `https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com` and use a JWT library to verify the signature. Use the value of `max-age` in the `Cache-Control` header of the response from that endpoint to know when to refresh the public keys.

The [JSON object at this endpoint](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com) is a `Record<string, string>` where the key is the key's ID and the value is the x509 public certificate. This differs slightly from the defined JWKS format that would return an object shaped like `{ keys: Record<string, string>[] }` (as seen when using regular [Google Accounts](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs)).